# place two divs per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

so I have X divs and I want to put 2 divs in one row next to each other. If the screen size width is below n px there should be 1 div per row.

Currently I have this

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}

@media(max-width: 300px) {
  #container {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"> 1 </div>
  <div class="box"> 2</div>
  <div class="box"> 3 </div>
  <div class="box"> 4 </div>
</div>
```

How can I limit the flex box to two divs per row?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add 50% width on .box and flex-wrap:wrap on the container

Additionally, what you did by changing display: flex to block was not required. Just change the .box elements width to 100%

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

@media(max-width: 300px) {
  .box {
     width: 100%;
   }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"> 1 </div>
  <div class="box"> 2</div>
  <div class="box"> 3 </div>
  <div class="box"> 4 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a property in your container class like

```
.container {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

And in box class just specify the width of your box as 50% like

```
.box {
 width: 50%;
 background: red;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Flex will do a trick for you.  `flex-wrap: wrap` for `#container` will make children wrap when necessary. `.box` with `50%` and after breakpoint `100%`.`

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap):

> The CSS flex-wrap property specifies whether flex items are forced into a single line or can be wrapped onto multiple lines. If wrapping is allowed, this property also enables you to control the direction in which lines are stacked.

If you are new to flexbox I recommend [this guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

#### Snippet

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

@media(max-width: 300px) {
  .box {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"> 1 </div>
  <div class="box"> 2 </div>
  <div class="box"> 3 </div>
  <div class="box"> 4 </div>
</div>
```